# Groovy create XML

Tags: xml, groovy

How can I create XML in Groovy?

```
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()
xml.langs(type:"current"){
  language("Java")
  language("Groovy")
  language("JavaScript")
}
```

Yeah, I know, it works..
But i need XML like this:

```
<root>
  <one param="var">
    <some param="var">variable</some>
    <some param="var">variable</some>
    ...
  </one>
  <two>
    <some param="var">variable</some>
    <some param="var">variable</some>
    <some param="var">variable</some>
    ...
  </two>
  ...
</root>
```

I will have loop in loop. Inner for  and outer for , ... but how can I add it to XML?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this to start with?

```
def outerLoop = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
def innerLoop = ['a', 'b']

def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()

xml.root {
    outerLoop.each { outer ->
        xml."$outer"(param: 'var') {
            innerLoop.each { inner ->
                xml."$inner"(params: 'abc', "value")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
And why don't I try it? I was thought, that it won't work :)